# PowerQuery: Avoid reload every time a column is added

Tags: excel, powerquery

How can I avoid a complete reload from the e.g. SQL Server every time I add / change a custom column in PowerQuery?
I'd like PowerQuery to work with the local (Data Model) data only unless I hit the refresh button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Table.Buffer` to keep the table in memory for subsequent calculations.